# Custom Post Type featured option

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, options, featured-post

I have created a Custom Post Type called `Products`.

Now I need a functionality that will allow me to select or check a product as featured. 
There can be only one featured product. 
When one product is selected the others are deselected automatically.
This featured product will be displayed on homepage.

**Question:**

What is the best way to store the `featured_product_id` to identify the one that is featured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to store product setting product wise as there will be only one featured product. You can store the `featured_product_id` in **options table**. And whenever a product is featured you just override the record in the options table, that why you can avoid the deselecting hassle of previously selected featured product.

Answer (score 0):

I create an options page and then have a list of all products there where I can choose the product to be featured.